# Can I gen original book based on translated ISBN in Python?

Tags: python

I have a following problem. Suppose I have two ISBNs of Harry Potter and the Philosopher`s Stone, one is a Czech translation, second is a German translation:

```py
isbn_cs = "9788000061917"
isbn_ger = "9783551318688"
```

I would like to match this books together, because they both come from the same original. Is there a library in python that make me able to find the name of the original? In this case it is "Harry Potter and the Philosopher´s Stone". Eventually ISBN of the original book would be also sufficient. I tried libraries `isbnlib` (https://pypi.org/project/isbnlib/3.6.1/) and `isbntools` (https://pypi.org/project/isbntools/3.3.8/), but it seems not suitable for my purpose. Can you help me, please?

Comment: What makes you think such a thing theoretically exists? Do ISBNs have relations between each other?

Comment: @luk2302 There must be a database with books` translations. Or is that an "anarchy" that nobody knows from what original was a book translated?